Define custom class operator in c++
I have this class which aims to mimic the behavior of a vector in MATLAB, I’m building this just as a college exercise.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

double const pi = 3.141592;

class mv{
    public:
        mv(size_t size = 0, double init = 0) {for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) a.push_back(init);};

        size_t size() const {return a.vector<double>::size();};
        void print() const {for(auto &el : a) std::cout << el << " ";}; 
        double get(size_t n) const {return a[n];};

        double& operator[](size_t n) {return a[n];};

    private:
        vector<double> a;
};

I want to add the multiplication by a scalar and I want it to work in both ways, i.e. both a * 3 and 3 * a should work as shown below.
int main() {
    mv a(5, 1);
    a[3] = 2;
    
    mv b(5);
    b = a * pi;
    b.print(); 
    cout << endl;

    mv c(5);
    c = pi * a;
    c.print(); 
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

The most obvious way to do this is
mv operator*(const mv& a, const double& scalar){
    mv res(a.size());
    for(size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++) res[i] = a.get(i) * scalar;
    return res;
};

mv operator*(const double& scalar, const mv& a){
    mv res(a.size());
    for(size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++) res[i] = a.get(i) * scalar;
    return res;
};

But I would really like to do it with just one function, so I’ve explored this option
template<typename T, typename V>
mv operator*(const T& lhs, const V& rhs){
    auto tuple = std::tie(lhs, rhs);
    return mvTimes(std::get<const mv&>(tuple), std::get<const double&>(tuple)); 
};

mv mvTimes(const mv& a, const double& scalar){
    mv res(a.size());
    for(size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++) res[i] = a.get(i) * scalar;
    return res;
};

This works but feels clumsy and prone to errors (for example I should then have to catch exceptions thrown by std::get). What is the best way to do this?

A side note: unlike C++, in Matlab arrays indices are 1-based (and not 0-based). If you want to keep this behavior you can handle it in mv::get and mv::operator[].

An operator*(const T& lhs, const V& rhs) in the global namespace without any restriction on T or V is just asking for trouble.

@WeijunZhou I agree, but is there a way to add a “restriction”? For example I would like to ask for one between T and V to be of type mv.

Before C++20, the typical way to add a restriction to a general template, other than specializing it, is using SFINAE. Since C++20, concepts should be used. However, your case may not be complicated enough to justify the use of either. For the very least, put the operator together with your classes in your own namespace, not the global one.

@WeijunZhou Thanks! I’ll take a look at all the things you mentioned, even if they’re overkill for this case at least I’ll learn something.

If you want to learn about SFINAE, maybe [tag:enable-if] can help.

placing the operator in the right namespace is not overkill. Its the least you should do.

Side note: consider using std::valarray. it might be a better fit for your use case. Also, you might want to read about expression templates to avoid unnecessary operations on vectors (although both those pieces of advice might be superfluous if the code is just for educational purposes).

@463035818_is_not_an_ai yeah when I said overkill I was obviously referring to SFINAE and concepts

You can define one operator in terms of the other:
mv operator*(const double& scalar, const mv& a){
    mv res(a.size());
    for(size_t i=0; i<a.size(); i++) res[i] = a.get(i) * scalar;
    return res;
};

mv operator*(const mv& a, const double& scalar){
    return scalar * a;
};


The fundamental operation here seems to be *=. I would define both versions of * in terms of that.

@john I don’t think that’s the case since, if I’m not mistaken, *= typically returns a reference while * returns a copy. The reason I point this out is because while defining custom operators I think it’s good practice to try to mimic what the standard does.

@FrancescoDerme You are correct but a reference can easily be converted to a copy. E.g. mv operator*(double scalar, mv a) { return a *= scalar; }. the reference returned by *= is returned by value in *.
